# why facebook api post to users and not on the page itself?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm using this code to post to my application page as the page and not the admin:

```
$page_info = $facebook->api("/344722062246773?fields=access_token");

 $attachment2 = array('message' => $row["nwmsg"],
                      'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
                      'name' => $row["nwnm"],
                      'caption' => $row["nwsubject"],
                      'picture' => 'http://itradegame.com/itrade/' . $row["nwposter"],
                      'description' => $row["nwtext"],
                      'actions' => array(array ('name'=> 'Play!','link'=> 'https://apps.facebook.com/itradee/')));

$result = $facebook->api('/344722062246773/feed/','post',$attachment2);
```

but the wierd thing is the users who likes the page can see the post on thier news feed but can't see it on the page itself.

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the new timeline feature, posts by users (all except the page itself) will be listed under 'Recent Posts by Others on { PAGE_NAME}' section.

Please check the section.

Comment: well i don't know what happened but it is working now. and another problem came out. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970936/why-posting-to-my-app-page-is-not-working-offline