# why posting to my app page is not working offline?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, cron

i'm using this code to post to my application page:

```
$page_info = $facebook->api("/344722062246773?fields=access_token");

$attachment2 = array('message' => $row["nwmsg"],
                  'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
                  'name' => $row["nwnm"],
                  'caption' => $row["nwsubject"],
                  'picture' => 'http://itradegame.com/itrade/' . $row["nwposter"],
                  'description' => $row["nwtext"],
                  'actions' => array(array ('name'=>'Play!','link'=>'https://apps.facebook.com/itradee/')));

 $result = $facebook->api('/344722062246773/feed/','post',$attachment2);
```

but the problem is that i'm schedualing this code to run in a specific time with a cron job and i recieve this error:

```
Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

thrown in

but if i run the page including this code manualy from my browser it works fine.

what is missing in this code?

Comment: does the code rely on session data, perhaps?

Comment: i logged out of my account and tried to run the code manually and i get the error, so it looks like it is a session relied but how to post offline??

Comment: i logged out of my account and tried to run the code manually and i get the error, so it looks like it is a session relied but how to post offline??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got it, i thought the publish stream permission will work but i also needed offline_access permission.